# Is it safe to use singleton ExecutorService

Tags: java, thread-safety, parallel-processing

Is it safe to use singleton `ExecutorService` and multiple instances of `CompletionService` using the same thread pool?

```
CompletionService<Object> collector = new ExecutorCompletionService<Object>(threadPool);
```

So, there will be multiple threads creating instances like above, 'collector' with one singleton threadPool.

Comment: I don't see any problem.  Did you have some particular issue in mind that might cause problems?

Comment: my guts feeling says there shld not be any problem. But i wanted to confirm before using it as I could not find and specific documentation on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be fine.  Each instance of `ExecutorCompletionService` maintains its own queue of completed tasks and just uses the underlying `Executor` to process each task.

The tasks may interfere with each other performance-wise if the number of completion services is large and the thread pool has an upper limit but that won't affect the correctness of the result.